# SSL handshake error with some Azure CLI commands

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-cli2

I am using Azure CLI in bash within PowerShell in Windows 10. I sit behind a corporate proxy. My goal is to automate the deployment and setup of Azure resources.

Some of the Azure CLI commands work perfectly fine: I can run az login, change the default subscription, list locations, resource groups, resources within resource groups and I can even run shell scripts to deploy resources like Key Vaults.

However, when I try to list the keys or secrets within a Key Vault, or create keys/secrets I get the following:

**Error occurred in request., SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxxxxx.vault.azure.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /secrets?api-version=7.0 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))**

The example I am providing here is for a Key Vault, but I am getting the same error with other types of resources, so I don't think the Key Vault is the issue.

When appending the `--debug` parameter to the command, I can see the error is coming from one of the Python libraries:

**urllib3.connectionpool : Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /secrets?api-version=7.0**

I have tried the suggestions provided at:

[Working with Azure CLI behind SSL intercepting proxy server](https://blog.jhnr.ch/2018/05/16/working-with-azure-cli-behind-ssl-intercepting-proxy-server/),

Including `export AZURE_CLI_DISABLE_CONNECTION_VERIFICATION=anycontent` to disable certificate check (not recommended) and `export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` to make Python requests use the system ca-certificates bundle.

I have also tried:

`export ADAL_PYTHON_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1`

which is suggested in the following post:

[[AzureStack] Handle SSL verification for certs not in Python root CA list #2267](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2267)

But unfortunately none of the above produced any change in the outcome.

I am using Azure CLI version 2.0.60 and Python 3.

Comment: something is off in your environment. you can use docker azure cli image and verify that it is working fine.

Answer (score 24):

Due to you were using Windows not Linux or MacOS, please try to use `set` instead of `export` to set the environment variables in PowerShell, as below, then to run the azure cli command for Key Vault again.

```
set ADAL_PYTHON_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
set AZURE_CLI_DISABLE_CONNECTION_VERIFICATION=1
```

And for the command `export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` on Linux, I think you can refer to the SuperUser thread https://superuser.com/questions/217719/what-are-the-windows-system-certificate-stores to run a powershell window as administrator (right click on the PowerShell shortcut and select `Run as administrator` to run).

However, as you said about `in bash with PowerShell`, it sounds like you open a bash shell session of Windows Subsystem for Linux or like Git Bash from `PS:` prompt, which described fuzzily that I can not understand for your operations, please post more details about it, and I don't think it's a good practice to use PowerShell with bash nested.

Answer (score 12):

Peter Pan's `set` method doesn't work well in PowerShell, use this instead:

```
$env:ADAL_PYTHON_SSL_NO_VERIFY = '1'
$env:AZURE_CLI_DISABLE_CONNECTION_VERIFICATION = '1'
```

Comment: This works in Powershell 7

Comment: Thank you. Saved my day. It was impossible for me to figure out what my corporate proxy is. But using these 2 commands in PowerShell Core worked like a charm.

Comment: it saved my life, thanks @kerr for sharing the hack.

Answer (score 8):

I've updated this with my comment from https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5099

@rzand 's process was the only one that worked for me, I'll expand on his solution though as there were extra steps required. All from elevated Shells

1. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python" -m pip install --upgrade pip`
2. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Scripts\pip" install python-certifi-win32`
3. Add the Cloud services root CA to `cacert.pem` exported from the downloaded certificate. I specifically needed [Microsoft IT TLS CA 5](https://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps/default.htm) and the "Baltimore CyberTrust Root" from that cert. Simply open the certs in text editor and append the contents to the bottom of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem`
4. Add the Self-signed certificate given to you by the network team. Simply open the cert in text editor and append the contents to the bottom of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem`
5. Set the system/environment variable in Command prompt `setx /m REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem"`
6. Set the system/environment variable in Powershell `$env:REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem"`
7. Close and open Bash / Command Prompt

FINALLY no errors. I can even retrieve Key Vault secrets

Comment: Remember to append your rootCA.pem to the bottom of the cacert.pem file. 


Refer: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5099#issuecomment-392605796 "Append the certificates from the trust chain at the end of the cacert.pem files (no need to append the leaf certificate. Only the root and intermediates are needed)"

Comment: Can you be more specific for step 3? I need to know how you get the those 2 certs you mention.

Answer (score 8):

Running just the below two commands, fixed the issue for me

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python" -m pip install --upgrade pip
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Scripts\pip" install python-certifi-win32

In my case the issue was seen due to invoking a Azure CLI command behind a company proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Having contacted the azure cli team, it appears there is a bug that affects keyvault commands that are run behind a proxy.

Refer to the following github issue that I created with an in-depth explanation of the issue (and a potential workaround):

[AZURE_CLI_DISABLE_CONNECTION_VERIFICATION does not have any effect for SSL verification](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9001)

The above issue is also linked to the following, which appears to be a duplicate:

[Az keyvault secret list --vault_name thru proxy is getting Proxy Authentication Required](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/6958)

It is also worth mentioning that this issue happens regardless of the platform the azure cli is running on so it is not an environmental issue or a problem when setting environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

Works on WSL Ubuntu 20.04

```
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

In order to make Python requests use the system ca-certificates bundle

Solution from [Working with Azure CLI behind SSL intercepting proxy server](https://blog.jhnr.ch/2018/05/16/working-with-azure-cli-behind-ssl-intercepting-proxy-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me in a corporate firewall and proxy.

- Added `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables to the system
- Find `certifi` path for your AZ CLI installation. It was `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi"` for me.
- Download your company root certificate and append it to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem"`

Done !

Comment: How do you this last step? "Download your company root certificate and append it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem"

Comment: Open both in a text editor and copy & paste.